# How to join tables on varchar fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
Table_1
type   |   description
Error      Some description
Success    Another description

Table_2
type   |   description
Error 1    Some description
Error 2    Another description
Error 3    Yet another description
```

I need to join these two tables by the type field, which is a varchar data type in both tables. The problem is that since "Error" is not the same as "Error 1" or "Error 2", when I compare both fields, it returns empty results. I've tried:

```
select * from Table_1 a
left join Table_2 using (type)

select * from Table_2
where type in (select distinct type from Table_1)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance

EDIT: I should be able to get results when a type in Table_1 is contained in a type in Table_2. I know it's a little hard to get, but the thing is that in Table_1 I have generic errors for different scenarios, and Table_2 contains these same errors, but with a little more information next to them. Table_2 is filled up with data that comes from log files, and there's pretty much anything I can do about it.

Comment: That's poor design; why aren't the types in Table_2 all `Error`, with a subtype of `Error 1`, `Error 2`, and `Error 3`?  What are your expected results?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I edited my question. Types in Table_2 cannot be all Error, because there are many different scenarios where that Error can be something else. Actually, I just typed Error in my question to make it generic, but it really could be anything

Comment: I agree with @LittleBobbyTables, that's a really bad design. Just put a primary key for table 1 `Table_1_ID` and use that as a column in table 2. That is called a foreign key. Your description of the relationship of these two tables fits a master-detail or parent-child relationship. If you can't change the design then you'll be left with using `like` in your `where` clause.

Comment: @AndyRefuerzo I agree with all you that these two tables have a bad design, but as I said before, there's nothing I can do about it. Table_2 cannot have a foreign key from Table_1, because its data comes from log files which don't have keys, but only text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your joins should be fine. A third way:

```
select * from Table_1 a
left join Table_2 b on a.type = b.type
```

If you're not getting any results then the `type` columns' values *are not equal*.

**Update**

Given that your comment states that `Table_1.type` is a substring of `Table_2.type`, you can change the join operator:

```
select * from Table_1 a
left join Table_2 b on b.type LIKE '%' + a.type + '%'
```

This practice is not ideal. Use with caution.

Comment: Types in both Table_1 and Table_2 will never be equal, but a portion of Table_1.type will always be contained in Table_2.type

Comment: @JoséRomero: Yikes. This is really poor design. I updated the code to show how you could do this, but you could easily end up with duplicates.